# apply bsxfun or arrayfun to every row of a matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, bsxfun

There are two matrices, `A` and `B` with size `m`-by-4 and `n`-by-4 respectively. My question is how to apply a function `f`, which takes two 1x4 vectors as input, on every row of A and B. The result will be a matrix with size `m`x`n`. The element [i, j] in `result` is `f(A(i, :), B(j, :))`.

For example:

```
A = rand(3, 4);
B = rand(5, 4);
for i = 1 : 3
    for j = 1 : 5
        result(i, j) = rectint(A(i, :), B(j, :));
    end
end
```

Can I use `bsxfun` or `arrayfun` to do this job?

Comment: My guess would be to that you do it just as you wrote - bsxfun is element-wise, I don't think you can abuse it like that.

Comment: Can you rewrite your `rectint` function to accept and return matrices?

Comment: @David, 'rectint' is matlab builtin function which is used to compute the overlap of the rectangle.

Comment: I think using `meshgrid` will be the easiest solution, as per Luis Mendo's answer.

Comment: @David: No need to rewrite `rectint`. It already handles matrices. Although, it sounds like this is just an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `arrayfun`, if you first use `meshgrid` to generate all combinations of rows:

```
[ii jj] = meshgrid(1:size(A,1),1:size(B,1));
result = arrayfun(@(n) rectint( A(ii(n),:), B(jj(n),:) ), 1:numel(ii) );
result = reshape(result, size(B,1), size(A,1)).';
```

You could of course substitute `rectint` by any other function that accepts two vector inputs and returns a number.

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is built into `rectint`. For the syntax `rectint(A,B)`:

> `A` and `B` can also be matrices, where each row is a position vector.
>       `AREA` is then a matrix giving the intersection of all rectangles
>       specified by `A` with all the rectangles specified by `B`.  That is, if `A`
>       is `M-by-4` and `B` is `N-by-4`, then `AREA` is an `M-by-N` matrix...

So, you can just do `result = rectint(A,B);` to get the matrix you are after.

Comment: yeah. rectint can handle matrices. Just using it as an example.

Comment: @FihopZz: Fair question. I just _had_ to point this out - thought I was going crazy. :) Anyway, Luis Mendo's answer is a spot-on demonstration for functions with vector input and scalar output, IMO.