# Efficient way to apply arrayfun to a matrix (i.e. R^N to R^M)

Tags: matlab

I have a function that transforms R^N to R^M.  For simplicity, lets just let it be the identity function `@(z) z` where z may be a vector.  I want to apply a function to a list of parameters of size `K x N` and have it map to `K x M` output.

Here is my attempt:

```
function out_matrix = array_fun_matrix(f, vals)
    for i=1:size(vals,1)
        f_val = f(vals(i,:));
        if(size(f_val,1) > 1) %Need to stack up rows, so convert as required.
            f_val = f_val';
        end
        out_matrix(i,:) = f_val;
    end
end
```

You can try it with

```
array_fun_matrix(@(z) z(1)^2 + z(2)^2 + z(3), [0 1 0; 1 1 1; 1 2 1; 2 2 2])
```

**The question:** Is there a better and more efficient way to do this with vectorization, etc.?  Did I miss a built-in function?

**Examples of non-vectorizable functions:** There are many, usually involving elaborate sub-steps and numerical solutions.  A trivial example is something like looking for the numerical solution to an equation, which in term is using numerical quadrature.  i.e. let `params = [b c]` and solve for the `a` such that `int_0^a ((z + b)^2) dz = c`

(I know here you could do some calculus, but the integral here is stripped down).  Implementing this example,

```
find_equilibrium = @(param) fzero(@(a) integral(@(x) (x + param(1)).^2 - param(2), 0, a), 1)
array_fun_matrix(find_equilibrium, [0 1; 0 .8])
```

Comment: With some quick tests it appears that the output is `z(input_data)` anyway i.e. you don't need that wrapper function, `array_fun_matrix`. Could you suggest us some other function for `z`, such that output is not `z(input_data)`?

Comment: Thanks.  Example changed.

Comment: How about you define your function according to the column format - `func1 = @(z) z(:,1).^2 + z(:,2).^2 + z(:,3)` and then use `func1(vals)` with vals as the input matrix, to get the output? That must be pretty efficient.

Comment: I understand what you are getting at, but there are lots of times where the function cannot be vectorized itself (hence the role of `arrayfun`.

Comment: Can you list out one case where the function can't be put in a vectorized way, given that you are always working on per row basis?

Comment: See the addition above

Comment: That's a complicated one indeed! Not sure if this would help, but have a look - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896630/apply-bsxfun-or-arrayfun-to-every-row-of-a-matrix

Comment: Interesting, thank you.  I just tried to use it as a specialized version of my problem for binary functions, but it started to have weird behavior depending on whether the function itself was vectorized or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `cellfun` function, but you'll need to manipulate your data a bit:

```
function out_matrix = array_fun_matrix(f, vals)
    % Convert your data to a cell array:
    cellVals = mat2cell(vals, ones(1,size(vals,1)));
    % apply the function:
    out_cellArray = cellfun(f, cellVals, 'UniformOutput', false);
    % Convert back to matrix:
    out_matrix = cell2mat(out_cellArray);
end
```

If you don't like this implementation, you can improve the performance of yours by preallocating the out_matrix:

```
function out_matrix = array_fun_matrix(f, vals)
    firstOutput = f(vals(1,:));
    out_matrix = zeros(size(vals,1), length(firstOutput)); % preallocate for speed.
    for i=1:size(vals,1)
        f_val = f(vals(i,:));
        if(size(f_val,1) > 1) %Need to stack up rows, so convert as required.
            f_val = f_val';
        end
        out_matrix(i,:) = f_val;
    end
end
```